# membership in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-2.x

```
fake = {'EmployeeID' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
         'ManagerID' : [3,3,5,6,5,4,5]
         'Name' : ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']}

df = pd.DataFrame(fake)
```

I am trying to match up members EmployeeID and ManagerID so I can figure out which employee is managed by which manager.

so my desire output has columns of 
[EmployeeID, Name, ManagerName].

only way I can think of is to copy the df and rename the columns so I can merge or join. However, I would rather do some other way that is more pythonic.

If you can give me a hint, that will be awesome.

Thank you.

Comment: column name "ManagerName" should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Use [*Series.map*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method to map the *ManagerID* column to their names based on `EmployeeID -> Name` correspondence, which can be created using`df.set_index('EmployeeID').Name` with *EmployeeID* as the index and *Name* as the value:

```
(df.assign(ManagerName = df.ManagerID.map(df.set_index('EmployeeID').Name))
   .drop('ManagerID', 1))

# EmployeeID  Name  ManagerName
#0         0    A       D
#1         1    B       D
#2         2    C       F
#3         3    D       G
#4         4    E       F
#5         5    F       E
#6         6    G       F
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting Up :

```
fake = {'EmployeeID' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
         'ManagerID' : [3,3,5,6,5,4,5],
         'Name' : ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']}
df = pd.DataFrame(fake)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
         'ManagerID' : [3,5,6,4],
         'managername' : ['AA','BB','CC','DD']})
```

Solution : `merge`

```
df.merge(df2,on='ManagerID',how='left')
Out[232]: 
   EmployeeID  ManagerID Name managername
0           0          3    A          AA
1           1          3    B          AA
2           2          5    C          BB
3           3          6    D          CC
4           4          5    E          BB
5           5          4    F          DD
6           6          5    G          BB
```